# getbounds when canvas rotate

Tags: android, canvas, rotation

I need to get the bounds of an image that is inside a canvas to detec if has been touched or not, but if I rotate the canvas the getbounds() maintain the same values, how con I get the correct values after canvas rotate?

```
//CODE ON VIEW CLASS:

    canvas.save();  
    canvas.rotate(rotation, Xpos, Ypos);

    secHandImg.setBounds(left,top,right,bottom);    
    secHandImg.setAntiAlias(true);
    secHandImg.draw(canvas);

    circleHandImg.setBounds(left,top,right,bottom); 
    circleHandImg.setAntiAlias(true);
    circleHandImg.draw(canvas);

    canvas.restore();


//CODE ON FRAGMENT CLASS:

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                Rect imageBounds = MyClass.secHandImg.getBounds();          

                int action = event.getAction();

                final int x = (int)event.getX();
                final int y = (int)event.getY();


                    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)   {

    if(x >= imageBounds.left && x < (imageBounds.left + imageBounds.width())
    && y >= imageBounds.top && y < (imageBounds.top + imageBounds.height())){

//THIS DON´T WORK IF CANVAS ROTATES 
                imageBoundsTouch = true;


                }

        }
```

Here an image to explain better my issue:

http://s11.postimg.org/z7j0xgwmb/Imagen_2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trigonometry to get the bounds of a rotated rectangle:

```
function BBoxDimensions(width,height,radianAngle){
  var c = Math.abs(Math.cos(radianAngle));
  var s = Math.abs(Math.sin(radianAngle));
  return({  width: height * s + width * c,  height: height * c + width * s });
}
```

And you can use trig to get the XY of the rotated bounding box:

```
// where cx/cy is the center of rotation of the target
// and startingX/startingY is the starting xy of the unrotated target

var x1 = startingX - cx;
var y1 = startingY - cy;
newX =cx+ x1*Math.cos(angle) - y1*Math.sin(angle);
newY =cy+ y1*Math.cos(angle) + x1*Math.sin(angle);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that did you see the image?

Comment: It´s not working I need the position on the screen, not the size of the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate your bounds values onOrientationChanged()

Comment: Thanks but I don´t rotate the screen I posted an image to explain the issue